# Как растянуть элементы по всей высоте другого блока?

Tags: html, css

Есть 2 блока, в каждом из которых есть по картинке, по заголовку и по описанию.
Выглядит это так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно сделать так без JS, JQUERY, FLEXBOX? В данном проекте использую display: table;

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.cards {
    display: table;
    margin-top: 45px;
}

.card {
    width: 45%;
    text-align: center;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.card-mg {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
}

.card-padding {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 5% 0 5%;
}

.card img {
    width: 100%;
}

.card h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.card h4 {
    font-weight: 100;
}
```

```html
<div class="cards">
                <div class="card card1">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFwoT.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="card-padding">
                        <h1>HEADING</h1>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, praesentium.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-mg">
                    
                </div>
                <div class="card card1">
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPzLT.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="card-padding">
                        <h1>HEADING</h1>
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, praesentium.</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Сделай просто таблицей

Comment: Было бы неплохо, если бы вы приложили картинки, которые используете в `html`, к посту, и использовали бы `url` картинок уже со странички данного поста. Ибо политика не позволяет грузить картинки со сторонних сайтиков, и ваш пример не воспроизводится как нужно...

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, нет, там будет много таких карточек разных размеров, а если я сделаю еще отдельную таблицу для заголовка и описания, то неудобно будет(((

Comment: @selya, приложил, изменил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если позволяет сделать фиксированный по высоте блок, то сделать обертку картинке и задать обертке `height:220px`

```
<div class="card card1">
        <div class="card__img">
    <img src="https://img.fonwall.ru/o/19/ComputerDesktopWallpapersCollection204_034.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="card-padding">
      <div class="card-padding__cell">
      <h1>HEADING</h1>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Non, praesentium.</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Стиль

```
.card__img{
  height: 220px;
 }
```

Comment: Другого выхода походу нет( Ладно, и на этом спасибо)

Comment: Есть но он вам не подходит, я пытался это решить таблицей но ка-то не получилось( Попробую еще, если что отпишу:)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ на свой вопрос.
Нужно было добавить картинку не через `img`, а через `backgound-image`.
И к картинке добавить:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

Answer (score 0):

Оберните картинки блоками и задайте не фиксированную высоту, а минимальную `min-height`. И установите приемлемое значение, это должно помочь.